# Why can I return my full query result but not a specified item from it?

Tags: python, list

I'm (*new to python*) trying to create a simple program using Tkinter to take a product code from a text box and return the cost from a database.

```
import pyodbc
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Cost Checker')
root.geometry("250x100")

#create connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXX;"
                      "Database=DataLake;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

#function to run SQL 
def Check():
  cursor = cnxn.cursor()
  cursor.execute('SELECT Products.ProductNumber, Products.EnglishDescription, Products.CurrentCost\
  FROM DataLake.dbo.Products Products\
  WHERE (Products.ProductNumber = ' + "'" + str(myTextbox.get()) + "'" + ')')

  list = cursor.fetchall()

  result = Label(root, text ="The cost of " + str(myTextbox.get()) + " is " + str(list))
  result.pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text="Enter a product number:")
myLabel.pack()

myTextbox = Entry(root, width=30)
Entry.focus(myTextbox)
myTextbox.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Submit", command = Check) #
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm struggling to pull out just the cost from the list.

The result I get is "The cost of X is [('X','X Description', Decimal('19.99'))]". So I know the query is returning a result.

The desired result is "The cost of X is 19.99".

I've tried changing

```
result = Label(root, text ="The cost of " + str(myTextbox.get()) + " is " + str(list))
```

to

```
result = Label(root, text ="The cost of " + str(myTextbox.get()) + " is " + str(list[2]))
```

to pull the 3rd element out but I get a list index out of range error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\pythonstuff\CostCheckerGUI.py", line 23, in Check
    result = Label(root, text ="The cost of " + str(myTextbox.get()) + " is " + str(list[2]))
```

It's probably something simple but when I search for the "IndexError: list index out of range", all results refer to trying to pull an index that doesn't exist.  I do know the cost is at [2] not [3].

Thanks in advance

newpy

Comment: @Carcigenicate is right check that you have `str(list[0][2]))` instead of `str(list[2]))`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the brackets in this: `[('X','X Description', Decimal('19.99'))]`.

This isn't a list of length three; it's a list of length one, holding a tuple of length three. You need to index into it twice: once to get the inner tuple, then again to get the data from the tuple:

```
tup = list[0]  # Get tuple
dec = tup[2]  # Get decimal
```

Or, combined:

```
dec = list[0][2]
```

---

Also, please do not use `list` as a name. That's a built-in function, and shadowing it will lead to pain later if you ever decide you want to use the built-in `list` function in the same scope.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on list, I just followed something I saw on youtube and that's what they used.

Comment: @newpy No problem. And if a tutorial is using names like that (and also `Check` should be lowercase since it's a function name), I'd be hesitant to trust them. There's *a lot* of bad tutorials out there. I avoid GeeksForGeeks, and a lot of YouTube like the plague.